# What happens if you don't declare any partials?

Tags: openmdao

Does openMDAO attempt to just work out all partials by finite difference, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no partials are declared, OpenMDAO will not compute partials for a given component.

When you want OpenMDAO to approximate all partials across a component via finite difference, include the following in your component's `setup` method:

```
self.declare_partials(of='*', wrt='*', method='fd')
```

The wildcards here expand to match any input or output name, so we're instructing OpenMDAO to approximate the partial of every output with respect to every input using the finite difference method.

For a more accurate approximation,  you can use the complex-step approach (assuming your underlying mathematical functions are complex-compatible).

```
self.declare_partials(of='*', wrt='*', method='cs')
```

The `declare_partials` method also allows you to specify a default value for the partials.  For instance, if a component computes the function:

```
outputs['z'] = 3*inputs['y']
```

For dz/dy, the derivative is constant so there's no need to repeatedly compute via approximation or in `compute_partials`.  Instead, we can just provide its default value in the `declare_partials` call and leave it at that.

```
self.declare_partials(of='z', wrt='y', val=3.0)
```

You can see how the behavior of an optimization changes by experimenting with the Paraboloid example shown here: http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/basic_guide/first_optimization.html

which uses the Paraboloid model as defined here:
http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/basic_guide/first_analysis.html